# How can I check element attribute after click before redirect?

Tags: cypress, assertion

I have a simple login form and I need to check whether button becomes disabled after clicking on it. The issue is that after click on submit, redirect happens, causing assertion step to fail due to element being detached from the DOM. My question is whether it is possible to somehow check visibility attribute of the element after click.

```
cy.get('[data-cy="email"]').type(this.user.email);
cy.get('[data-cy="password"]').type('valid');
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click().should('be.disabled'); // this fails due to dettachment from the DOM.
```

I've attempted to use .then() after click, but that did not help. Using cy.intercept() is also not an option due to how app is written.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: You'll have to requery for the submit button since it becomes disabled after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click()
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('be.visible').and('be.disabled')
```

Comment: can you add the HTML of the button in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the message "element is detached from DOM", it means an action on the page (in this case `submit` event) has replaced the element with a new version.

If you want to check that the ***old*** version of the element has the disabled attribute, this kind-of works.

```js
cy.get('button[type="submit"]')
  .click()
  .should($el => {
    const disabledAttr = $el.attr('disabled')
    expect(disabledAttr).to.eq('disabled')
  })
```

But I think this would be flaky if there is a delay between `.click()` and the disabled attribute getting applied.

If you want to check that the ***new*** version of the element has the disabled attribute, this should work.

```js
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();
cy.get('button[type="submit"]').should('be.disabled'); // runs after "page load" event
```

Comment: So - the button gets disabled but really it doesn't matter because the page changes completely and the button does not exist on the new page? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: And if you stop at a blank page, why don't you just go back? Or let the redirect happen and then go back?